# Unsolved external symbol "sprintf_s" while making windows native application. Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c, linker, native, visual-studio-2022, ntdll

I am using Visual studio 2022 and am trying to make a windows native application in c. That means I can also link against ntdll.lib. I am trying to use the function sprintf_s and the linker throws an error. I am trying to use sprintf_s like this

```c
WCHAR str[255];
sprintf_s(str, 255, L"ERROR: Unable to open keyboard device. Error code: %02x", status);
```

I tried searching google and it didn't give me any results and I also did try to manually declare it in a header file.

Like this

```c
int sprintf_s(
    char* buffer,
    size_t sizeOfBuffer,
    const char* format,
    ...
);
```

And yet it still does not work.
Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What linker?  What options are passed to it?

Comment: And FWIW, [the `snprintf()` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.5) is **required** to be implemented by any standard-conforming C implementation, it is **not** "deprecated", and it's every bit as safe as `sprintf_s()`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention what linker. Im using MSVC

Comment: I'll also try snprintf()

Comment: sprintf_s does not accept a wchar. Did you include stdio.h?

Comment: Im also using /NODEFAULTLIB

Comment: why are you using NODEFULTLIB?

Comment: Im trying to make a Windows Kernel Application. Using NTDLL.

Comment: *Im also using /NODEFAULTLIB*  The actual implementation of functions such as `sprintf_s()` are normally in those "default libraries" that you've told the linker not to use.  What exactly do you mean by a "Windows Native Application"?  Windows applications would normally link in all kinds of Windows libraries.

Comment: A native application uses the windows nt subsystem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Native_API

Comment: Writing drivers is hard. Solving linker errors is not. Start from the beginning, not the end.